# How would I make the html5 input to accept only email addresses from gmail.com using patter attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I am using html input control to feed in email address. Also, I am using required attribute but I want the input should only be from gmail.com i.e. john@gmail.com, aamir@gmail.com etc and not any other domain.

```
<input type="text" name="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@domain\.[a-zA-z]+$" required>
```

But this accept every domain and not only gmail.com.

NOTE: I need to do it with regex in html5 control not with javascript etc

Update: I am using razor syntax with asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@gmail\.com$
```

[image]

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@gmail\.com$" required></input>
<input type='submit' placeholder='submit'/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks bro but when I use this then It says that @gmail doesn't exist in current context. I am using razor syntax

Comment: @Stacky i am not familiar with razor syntax, can you create minimal example ?

Answer (score 1):

In Razor page `@` has special meaning. `@` is used to add code in a Razor page.
You have to escape `@`.

Try

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@("@")gmail\.com$
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a javascript function that validates the input before usage using the regex given by Code Maniac. This function could be called each time form submission is initiated using the "onsubmit" attribute.