# How can i add specific email validation for html

Tags: html, validation

I would like to know how to only allow @gmail.com and @yahoo.com for my email validation in html. I know about the <input type="email" validation but that would allow emails in any format and I only want those two to be accepted. How do I do it??

Comment: `<input type="email" pattern="@(gmail|yahoo)\.com$" />`

Comment: Does this solve your Problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57344101/how-would-i-make-the-html5-input-to-accept-only-email-addresses-from-gmail-com-u

Comment: @j08691 that's it!!! thank you so much, how do i upvote you? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is RegExp

1. If you are using a framework (angular/react/vue) they have there own(compatible third party) libraries to handle form validation.
2. If you are using plain JS you can add onchange event with your input and test the input with desired regex or before submitting the form you can test the input.

Regex you will need

/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.]*@(gmail|yahoo).com$/gm

More about Regex with Javascript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: What about the pattern attribute for html input elements?

Comment: Thank you so much! :D @Marcel good question, i was wondering too

Comment: Actually I was looking for an answer for plain html cause i don't know javascript so maybe if anyone knows with the pattern attribute?

Comment: Yea you can actually use the pattern attribute will work with the RegExp I mentioned.

Comment: oh okay thank you so much!! to everyone as well :D

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, the only correct answer was given by @j08691 in the comments to the question. `<input type="email" pattern="@(gmail|yahoo)\.com$" />`. No javascript needed. It 's all done with html.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is not the best way of achieving this, for best way use it at backend, with PHP email validation filter.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="emailForm" action="" method="post">
<label for="email">E-mail</label><br>
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your 
email" value="">
<button onclick="validate();" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Inline javascript, you can carry it later, keep it under html for testing purposes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
var email = $('#email').val();

if (email.length == 0) {
  window.alert("you didn't enter an email");
}

if (!email.includes('@')) {
  window.alert("you mail is unvalid");
}

var emailHost = email.substr((-1)*(email.length - email.indexOf('@') - 1));

var allowedDomains = ["gmail.com","hotmail.com","yahoo.com"];

var inAllowed = false;
for(i=0;i<allowedDomains.length;i++){
  if (allowedDomains[i] == emailHost) {
    inAllowed = true;
  }
}

if (!inAllowed) {
  window.alert("your e-mail hosting not supported");
}else { //submit form here
  window.alert("success");
  $('#emailForm').submit();
}

}
</script>
```

And back end get email from $_POST if using php

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing, thank you so much!! I'm not good with javascript yet so i just wanted to know how to do it in html, but this is good future reference

Comment: do not exaggarate javascript, it is one of the easiest things that you can learn, You will finish it in 2-3 days, but as i said it is still not the best way. If you are using Php you should check FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL and FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL, then you check emails at backend and inform users with ajax instead of jquery window alerts, it is the right way. Keep hard working, good luck !